# Is it recommended to train a SVM model with the same dataset used for pre-train an autoencoder?

Tags: svm, autoencoders, train

I have a very limited dataset and have used 80% of it to pre-train an autoencoder.

Now, I attached the enconder part to a SVM. In order to train the SVM, is ok to train it using the exactly same (80%) dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be fine. The auto-encoder only performs a pre-selection of the features, so it has nothing to do with the actual model. Just make sure you never mix data to train and to test/validate a model!

Comment: have you find this statement in any book/paper?